# linq query to datatable error vb

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, dataset

I'm trying to send the results of a linq query to a new datatable. I will then use this datatable as a datasource for a datagridview. Aim being for edits made in datagridview to go back to the dataset and in turn to the xml. Followed this, here:

[msdn guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

with this code:

```
   Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(My.Settings.CfgFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    _XMLRawDS.ReadXml(xmlFile)

    Dim _XMLquery = From xmlsystem In _XMLRawDS.Tables("system").AsEnumerable()
        Join xmlcontroller In _XMLRawDS.Tables("controller").AsEnumerable() On xmlsystem.Item("system_Id") Equals xmlcontroller.Item("system_Id")
        Join xmlinput In _XMLRawDS.Tables("input").AsEnumerable() On xmlinput.Item("controller_Id") Equals xmlcontroller.Item("controller_Id")
        Join xmlport In _XMLRawDS.Tables("port").AsEnumerable() On xmlport.Item("input_Id") Equals xmlinput.Item("input_Id")
        Join xmlnewseq In _XMLRawDS.Tables("newseq").AsEnumerable() On xmlnewseq.Item("port_Id") Equals xmlport.Item("port_Id")
        Select New With
        {
            .input = xmlsystem.Field(Of String)("Input"),
            .name = xmlsystem.Field(Of String)("Name"),
            .id = xmlcontroller.Field(Of String)("id"),
            .type = xmlport.Field(Of String)("type"),
           .newseqtext = xmlnewseq.Field(Of String)("newseq_Text")
            }
    Dim _XMLCtrlsDT As DataTable = _XMLquery.copytodatatable()
```

However, the last line won't compile due to:

```
'copytodatatable' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>)'.
```

Looks pretty much the same as the msdn one to me, but sure there's something quietly at work.. Did take a look at this, but I'm damned if I could get it to work...

[msdn-Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

not even confident that's the issue..

The XML is as below:

```
<!-- 
    Configuration Remap file
-->
<mameconfig version="10">
    <!-- 
    ############################################################
    Define controller aliases, This just makes the controller names
    a little easier to deal with for the rest of the file.
    ############################################################
    -->
    <controlleralias>
        <id>Ultimarc Ultra-Stik Player 1</id>
        <alias>U360 Player1</alias>
    </controlleralias>
    <controlleralias>
        <id>WingMan Extreme Digital 3D</id>
        <alias>Flightstick</alias>
    </controlleralias>
    <controlleralias>
        <id>HID#VID_061C_PID_AA00#7_35df86d5_0_0000#</id>
        <alias>Lightgun1</alias>
    </controlleralias>

    <!-- 
    ############################################################
    This is the System Default section
    It generally should be the FIRST system section in the cfg file
    ############################################################
    -->
    <system name="default">
        <!-- put a controller element here to have it copied into ONLY this particular
         system element
    -->
        <controller id="U360 Player1">
            <input>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_UP">
                    <newseq type="standard">JOYCODE_YAXIS_UP_SWITCH</newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_DOWN">
                    <newseq type="standard">
                        JOYCODE_YAXIS_DOWN_SWITCH
                    </newseq>
                </port>
            </input>
        </controller>
        <controller id="Flightstick">
            <input>
                <port type="P1_SELECT">
                    <newseq type="standard">JOYCODE_BUTTON_7</newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="START1">
                    <newseq type="standard">JOYCODE_BUTTON8_SWITCH</newseq>
                </port>
            </input>
        </controller>
        <!-- this keyboard section provides a way to specify keyboard input
         mappings that should ALSO be made for the specific port types. -->
        <controller id="keyboard">
            <input>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_UP">
                    <newseq type="standard">KEYCODE_UP</newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_DOWN">
                    <newseq type="standard">KEYCODE_DOWN</newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_LEFT">
                    <newseq type="standard">KEYCODE_LEFT</newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_RIGHT">
                    <newseq type="standard">KEYCODE_RIGHT</newseq>
                </port>
            </input>
        </controller>

        <!-- 
        ###################################################
        ACTUAL INPUT MAPPING STARTS HERE
        DO NOT actually put anything in this section.
        It is completely cleared and regenerated!
        ###################################################
        -->
        <input></input>
    </system>


    <!-- 
    ###################################################
    This is a GAME specific section
    Add additional <controller> sections here
    to define how those controllers should map for this
    particular game
    ###################################################
    -->
    <system name="ribbit">
        <!-- This would be stupid to actually use, but as an example
         For this game ("Ribbit"), reverse the UP and DOWN directions
         on the joystick -->
        <controller id="U360 Player1">
            <input>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_UP">
                    <newseq type="standard">
                        JOYCODE_YAXIS_DOWN_SWITCH
                    </newseq>
                </port>
                <port type="P1_JOYSTICK_DOWN">
                    <newseq type="standard">
                        JOYCODE_YAXIS_UP_SWITCH
                    </newseq>
                </port>
            </input>
        </controller>
        <!-- 
        ###################################################
        ACTUAL INPUT MAPPING STARTS HERE
        DO NOT actually put anything in this section.
        It is completely cleared and regenerated!
        ###################################################
        -->
        <input></input>
    </system>
</mameconfig>
```

Which results in a Dataset of 7 tables (mameconfig, controlleralias, system,controller,input,port,newseq). All appear to have primary and foreign keys inserted by the import xml process.

Would appreciate any help. Really stuck on this one..

Comment: `Select New With...` makes an `Anonymous` type so it's not a `DataTable` so it has no `.copytodatatable` member.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I knew better about how you got the data and if a Custom Class would suite you better. `List(Of customClass)` is usable with DataBinding and lends itself better for `LINQ` queries as well. So if you posted a well described problem and then a solution may arise. Here you are trying to do something with a `DataTable` that probably should be done in the `SQL` string.

Comment: Thank you. I shall amend my problem.